# Alias to move and activate virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, fish

I'm working a lot with Python. A while ago I switched to fish. Mainly because I don't really use a lot of bash scripts (I used to, but for my work it's mainly not useful).
I got several virtualenv for python compatibility. There is like 2/3 virtualenvs per version of django (3 versions) which makes it to 9 venvs. Now here is a script (at least a part of the script) I used with bash :

```sh
if [[ $1 == "myproject" ]]; then
    cd $HOME/Prog/Scripts/Python/project/
    if [[ $2 == "--env" ]]; then
        source ../dj1.6-3.3venv/bin/activate
    fi
    if [[ $3 == "--run" ]]; then
        python manage.py runserver
    fi
fi
```

Now I got a simple alias with fish which is :

```sh
alias project_django='cd ~/Prog/Scripts/Python/project/; and source ../dj1.6-3.4.1venv/bin/activate.fish'
```

Although it works, it destroys my prompt and just gives me the usual `>` which removes the git functions, current working directory and such.

Is there a way I can fix this ? Like by calling the fish prompt initialisation ? Does anyone got the same issue and how did you fix it ?

Comment: I removed the django tag since your question would apply even if you were not using django. Also, please do not use the title of your post to tag your post.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. That's enjoyable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. It seems that the size of the prompt was too large. When the current size of the terminal is too small for the prompt to be displayed, it just displays the classical `>`. Even though that's stupid, it may help some people around here to know that... Just resize the window of your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else already faced this issue, and created [`virtualfish`](http://virtualfish.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), the documentation of which contains [a section on customzing the prompt](http://virtualfish.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#customizing-your-fish-prompt):

> virtualfish doesn’t attempt to mess with your prompt. Since Fish’s
>   prompt is a function, it is both much less straightforward to change
>   it automatically, and much more convenient to simply customize it
>   manually to your liking.
>
> The easiest way to add virtualenv to your prompt is to type funced
>   fish_prompt, add the following line in somewhere:

```
if set -q VIRTUAL_ENV
    echo -n -s (set_color -b blue white) "(" (basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV") ")" (set_color normal) " "
end
```

> Then, type funcsave fish_prompt to save your new prompt to disk.

Comment: Actually fish must have evolved a bit and now supports virtualenvs. There is actually a .fish script in every virtualenv created which permits to activate the virtualenv with fish. I'll have a look at this virtualfish though it may become useful at some point. Thank you.